# hide and show RadComboBox

Tags: jquery, telerik

I am trying to hide and Show RadcomboBox. But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$.ajax({ 
            url: applicationPath + "/test/Test.svc/GetResultById", 
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "json", 
            data: '{"sId":' + sender.get_value() + '}', 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            success: function(result) 
             { 
                  var combo = "<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");

                  if(result.d == false) 
                  { 

                    combo.hideDropDown(); 
                  } 
                  else
                  {
                    combo.showDropDown();
                  }
             }
```

Comment: Please check below link. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcombobox.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `$find` to RadComboBox          See [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/hide-drop-down-on-client.aspx)

```
var combo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
```

to `Hide` the RadComboBox dropdown

```
combo.hideDropDown();
```

TO `Show` RadComboBox dropdown

```
combo.showDropDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this page, you should identify your combo with the following code:

```
var combo = <%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>;
```

So maybe try losing the quotation marks and the closing parentheses (which probably shouldn't be there anyway) on that row.

Also, `ShowDropDown()` and `HideDropDown()` begin with capital letters.

If you are still running into problems, try running it in FireBug with the Javascript debugger turned on (or even just put in Alert() calls to test and make sure that the script gets all the way through without any errors and is properly identifying the combo object).

Comment: I am using FireBug and debugged the code. It's going through hideDropDown() but it didn't do anything. Also capital letters with HideDropDown() throwing error message. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with combo.set_visible(false);

Answer (score 0):

hideDropDown and showDropDown only closes and opens it. See the reference [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcomboboxitem.html)

If you actually want to hide the drop down on the client site you will need to get a reference to the combo box and then do this (see [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcomboboxitem.html) too):

```
combo.set_visible(false)
```